# How to hash a long in c++?

Tags: c++

`std::hash` for a `long` is the identity function. This can causes poor hash distributions (e.g., if all the values are even, all hashes will also be even, etc). Is there a better way to hash a `long`?

Answer (score 1):

> if all the values are even, all hashes will also be even

And that's fine, because they're not used as is. Imagine if you allocated 4 billion buckets for one dictionary, it would be faster to just implement a linear search. Much, much faster.

Instead they're used to allocate a co-prime number of items (and usually a straight up prime number), for the very reason you mention.

All a hash has to do is to be as different as possible for different input values (and when it can't, at least be different for the most common or close values), and an identity function for a `long` (which is, I'm assuming, the same size of your hash) is the perfect candidate.

Comment: Do modern hash tables even use prime-number capacity? At least some of them use power-of-two sizes and simply mask the hash value to obtain the position, as masking is much cheaper than modulus. For example, the [Swiss table](https://abseil.io/about/design/swisstables) explicitly recommends "a hash function that distributes entropy across the entire bit space well" for performance reasons.

Comment: From the .Net Framework 4.8 `HashSet<T>` source code: "The capacity is always prime; so during resizing, the capacity is chosen as the next prime greater than double the last capacity. "

Comment: Also your quote says exactly what I said: the identity function is the perfect candidate to hash a `long`, as it distributes entropy equally across the entire bit space.